# How to use Bezier Path to change UIImage to a marker shape?

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimage, uibezierpath, nsbezierpath

I need to change the shape of a UIImage to that of a marker. I tried to combine 2 UIImages but the result was not sufficient. Is Bezier Path, a useful solution in such a case?
[image]

This will be a sample shape to which I need to convert my UIImage.

Comment: Apply UIBezierPath to UIImage?  That's not impossible except that it won't be that easy.  Why don't you just apply a path to UIView?

Comment: Anything that'd work would do. Except, how can I get a UIView to this shape?

Comment: Use CAShapeLayer and set a path to it.  Then add that sublayer to a UIView object.